# Self-adjoint matrices: prove that $\operatorname{Tr}\left((AB)^2\right)\le\operatorname{Tr}\left(A^2B^2\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A,B \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and self-adjoint. Prove the following inequality:
$\operatorname{Tr}\left((AB)^2\right)\le\operatorname{Tr}\left(A^2B^2\right)$.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the brute-force method?  Just expand the sums of products and what do you get?

Comment: $\operatorname{Tr}\left(AB\right)^2$ is ambiguous notation. (Corrected.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $(AB - BA)$ is skew-Hermitian. It follows that $\text{Tr}[(AB - BA)^2] \leq 0$.

Comment: Very nice! But proving that $\operatorname{Tr}\left(U^2\right) \leq 0$ for any skew-Hermitian matrix $U$ is a **lot** simpler than whatever you do with the eigenvalues. :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg that's news to me.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: $\operatorname{Tr}\left(U^2\right) = \sum_{i,j} u_{i,j} u_{j,i}$ where $u_{i,j}$ denotes the $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry of $U$. See it now?

Comment: Yes.  Very clever!